# CSS/(PHP/HTML?) Background

Tags: php, html

For my site I've been trying to get the background to WORK and to REPEAT, but there's something wrong I guess? 
This is my code:

```
    body
{
    background-image:url('../images/backkground.png');
}
```

and then it's included in the index like this:

```
<?php include 'style.css'; ?>
```

Yeah I know, those php tags but that's placed before all the rest.
Does anyone have tips on what I'm doing wrong? (If I AM doing something wrong)

Comment: Two 'k' in background.png?

Comment: The 2 K's are righ...

Comment: The image doesn't appear. The gray background that it is now stays.

Comment: Unless the `include` isn't working @chris85

Comment: Are you sure `include` is the right thing to use here? why not `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`?

Comment: What do I have to change then @HPierce?

Comment: If you put the CSS directly on the index page, does it work? That would help determine if the include is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [PHP's include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) wrong. What you're doing is including the contents of the file **server side**.

You want to include the stylesheet in the HTML output:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

In PHP this would look like:

```
<?php
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">';
?>
```

It could also be a problem with **where** the file is. It should be in the same directory as the calling page so if you're on `site.com/index.php` you should be able the see the css file at `site.com/style.css`.

Comment: Thank you sir! This was the solution :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't use PHP to include a CSS file, you reference it in HTML:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/style.css" type="text/css">
```

Ideally you place this in the `<head></head>` tags at the top of the HTML page.

Comment: What kind of server error? Did you place it in the head tags? Was the path in the `href` attribute correct?

Comment: That is caused by PHP, not HTML. Can you edit your post and give us the markup for your page? Have you looked in your error logs for the 500 reason?

Comment: @FridgeProduction, HTMLs don't give you server errors, that is for sure.

Comment: Yeah sajib, but someone said to edit the tags and remove php and change it to html (the tags)

Answer (score 0):

As the others already told you, you are using the include in the server side, you should use something like

```
<?php
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">';
?>
```

But if for any reason you need to use the server side include, you could try the following:

```
<style>
  <?php include 'style.css'; ?>
</style>
```